# Using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager at a later time

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I'm using `AFNetworking` for my app.
I want to create a queue mechanism with different priority for each `HTTP request`.
For that - I need to be able to create an `HTTP Request` using `AFNetowrking` but use it later.

The example for creating an HTTP request is:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This code will send the request immediately.
How can I just create the request (method, parameters, url), but use it at a later time?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out you need to create an AFHTTPRequestOperation instead of a manager.

Full article here:
http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/

Comment: That article is about AFNetworking 1.x. Only AFNetworking 1.x has AFHTTPClient. The question is about AFNetworking 2.x, which has AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Answer (score 4):

Check operationQueue of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. If you suspend it before adding request, it will not run until you resume operation queue. For example:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
```